# How can I remotely log out of my Google account on a recently used device?

Tags: google-account, security, logout

I have noticed a device I don't recognize in the [list of recently used devices in my Google account](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity). I'm not overly-concerned about it, because I think the device belongs to one of my family members, but I would still like to log out of it remotely. However, that doesn't seem possible. From an internet search, it seems that this is a fairly recent change, as it used to be possible in the past. What options do I have, other than changing my password? Has Google made this change because they are trying to get me to change my password more often?

Answer (score 3):

I went to this https://myaccount.google.com/
Then clicked the "security" tab
Scrolled down to "my devices"
Then it shows all the devices you are logged into
Click the 3 dots "options" tab and click log out

Answer (score 2):

The "Device activity & security events" section of https://MyAccount.google.com will show you all of the devices that have been used to log into your account recently, but you can't force a logout from there. The only way to logout of other devices is to change your password, and that will log you out of everything except the device you use to change your password.

Comment: Will enabling two-step verification not sign me out of my devices?

Comment: Probably? I've had 2FA on so long I don't even remember whether it kicks you off other devices. It's worth a try.

Comment: Not true anymore. I just changed my password in my gmail and my phone kept have access to my gmail, google drive and so one..

Comment: There is now a logout option in the devices view described here

Answer (score -1):

Logging out of Gmail remotely is a great idea if you've accidentally left yourself logged in on a public computer you no longer have access to, like in a library or school. The same screen for logging out of web sessions is also useful for seeing from where your account has been accessed recently, including the apps that have access to your Gmail.

1. Open Gmail on a computer and scroll to the very bottom of the page below all of your messages.
2. Click or tap the **Details** link on the bottom right. It's right next to a sentence that reads "Last account activity:"
3. Choose the **Sign out all other web sessions** button.

[image]

Note these facts about signing out of your account from the last account activity page:

- You will not be signed out of the current session you're using to access this option.
- This does nothing to your Gmail password, so if another user has access to your account because they know your password or it's stored in their browser, and that's why you've logged them out, the only way to be sure that they don't get into your account again is to change your Gmail password.
- Email clients connecting through IMAP are not signed out. For example, if you're logged on through the Gmail mobile app as well, you will remain logged on.

Comment: This answer is super decieving and dangerous! "Details" in Gmail will only show Gmail sessions, but will not show all Google Account sessions! For example, if you are logging in just docs.google.com, the session won't be listed there! So you might think "whoa I am safe, I am not logged anywhere else", but it's not true! Then, gmail can be open any time on that machine without giving a password! @ahorn